# I am learning BeautifulSoup but I am getting an error

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Here is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get("https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

urls = []
for h2_tag in soup.find_all("h2"):
    a_tag = h2_tag.find('a')
    urls.append(a_tag.attrs not in ['href'])

print(urls)
```

Here is the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'
```

what is wrong with my code

Comment: if you accept an answer, its good practice to upvote the answer to show respect to the person who spent time to read your question and tried to solve your issue. We should encourage each other's effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes `h2_tag.find('a')` will return `None`. You can fix this problem by using a `try`/`except`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get("https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

urls = []
for h2_tag in soup.find_all("h2"):
    try:
        a_tag = h2_tag.find('a')
        urls.append(a_tag.attrs["href"])
    except AttributeError:
        continue

print(urls)
```

Answer (score 1):

My preference for cleaner code is to put the restriction into the selection of nodes, rather than test later. In your case, you can do this by using css selectors which retrieve `h2` that have an `a` child. Similar layout to yours:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get("https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
urls = []

for h2_tag in soup.select('h2:has(a)'):
    a_tag = h2_tag.find('a')
    urls.append(a_tag['href'])

print(urls)
```

---

However, we can be much more concise than the above:

```
urls = [i['href'] for i in soup.select('h2 > a')]
print(urls)
```

The above selecting `a` elements which are direct children of `h2`.